# Regular Expressions: Remove character before match

Tags: regex

I was wondering if there was a way to use Regular expressions to remove *n* occurrences of characters right before *n* matches of `[removebefore]`

Might be unclear, but an example explains everything:

`This is a teststring[removebefore][removebefore][removebefore]. blablabla[removebefore][removebefore]`

should be changed into

`This is a teststr. blablab`

Of course this can be done by matching and replacing `/.\[removebefore\]/` a dozen of times, but is there a way to do this in one regexp?

EDIT:
I was trying to do this in PHP. And indeed I am searching for a regular expression that matches `[anychar]{n}\[removebefore\]{n}` where n is the number of removebefore's.

Comment: Which language are you using? Just do a global replace.

Comment: Your chosen language probably provides tools to do this, with or without regexp. Python would be `mystring.replace('[removebefore]', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using `perl`

Regular expression:

```
s<([^\[]+)((?:\[removebefore\])+)><substr( $1, 0, length($1) - scalar(split(/]\[/, $2)) )>ge
```

Test:

Content of *script.pl*:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s<([^\[]+)((?:\[removebefore\])+)><substr( $1, 0, length($1) - scalar(split(/]\[/, $2)) )>ge;
    print;
}   

__DATA__
This is a teststring[removebefore][removebefore][removebefore]. blablabla[removebefore][removebefore]
```

Running script:

```
perl script.pl
```

And result:

```
This is a teststr. blablab
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, regex match things. They don't delete or modify input.

A pretty straightforward algorithm would be:

1 - Read your input counting the characters until you get to a [removebefore].

2 - When you get to [removebefore], count the number of [removebefore] in another variable.

3- Subtract the number of [removebefore] from the number of characters and save it in a variable, let's call it "n".

4 - Go again through your input, printing the first "n" number of characters.

There is some error handling to be done in this algorithm, but that's basically it.